# cakephp xml parser missing child arrays

Tags: xml, arrays, cakephp, multidimensional-array, xml-parsing

cakephp xml parser missing some nested arrays while parsing the xml.

kindly help me please.

Comment: we expect input/output and code (*causing the problem*)

Answer (score 0):

cakes xml class is quite [bad](http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648-cakephp/tickets?q=xml), rather use simpleXml